# can Postgresql create an index on array length?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, indexing, postgresql-9.4

I am working on a Rails app, that stores data in a Postgresql 9.4 database, the `products` table has a column `images` which is an `array`, I'd like to get the products that have no images, i.e. `array_length(images) = 0`. Is it possible to create an index on this condition? i.e on the length of the array.

Comment: What is the type of `images`? Is it a BLOB?

Comment: it's of type `array`, it's a Postgresql non standard type, it just contains the urls of the images. not the images themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can create an expression index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON products ((array_length(images));
```

Comment: You should accept this answer if it works @NafaaBoutefer